# How to use grep/sed/awk to get specific key's value in the json file?

Tags: bash, shell

```
{"version":"5.2","issues":
[{"key":"1111",
"component":"abns",
"line":15,
"startLine":15,
"startOffset":10,
"endLine":15,
"endOffset":14,
"message":"Not found",
"Major":"level2",
"rule":"xml:Empty",
"status":"close",
"isNew":true,
"Date":"2019-05-11 08:36:55"}],
"component":[{"key":"Github"},
{"key":"xxx.xml","path":"xxx.xml","modKey":"absorbs","status":"ADD"},{"key":"seed","path":"555","modKey":"absorbs"}],
"rules":[{"key":"xml:Not_Be_Empty","rule":"Empty","repository":"xml","name":"Empty"}],"user":[xxxx]}
```

I tried to use following command to get value of `"Major"`:

```
sed -E 's/.*\"issues\":.*\"Major\":\"([^\"]*)\",.*/\1/' xxx.json
```

But it did not work. Can anyone help me out without using jq? Thanks

Comment: sed/grep is too format dependent. May  be you can use https://stedolan.github.io/jq/?

Comment: Please post valid JSON, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use a tool that can parse JSON, sed and grep are line oriented and can't help you reliably. For example, using `jq`:

```
$ jq -r '.issues[0].Major' file.json
level2
```

Comment: Hi choroba, are there any ways to use grep/awk?

Comment: No reliable ones.